# Spaces between edges and loopcut

Tags: modeling

[image]

Wanted to make the right loopcut have the same spaces between the edges and the loopcut just like the left one. how do you have the absolute spaces cuz i want to make a table and 2 of em have to have the same spaces or it would look weird. my question is how to make the same spaces like the left one so the right one can have the same spaces between the edge and the loopcut. Thank you

Comment: suggest mirror to other side, otherwise you need check the one side distance and loopcut to corner (factor=0 or 1) and then offset the distance.

Comment: Thanks also for the information dear sire but i find it hard to understand w/o Video cuz im still blender adept (17 days in blender)

Comment: Another suggestion would be to create a single loop cut across the middle of your object then, with the loop still selected, use CTRL-B to bevel it. Moving the mouse during the bevel operation moves the resulting edges symetrically.

Comment: Thanks i put that in mind

Comment: I'll add that as an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As XY says, if the width is not the same, the solution is probably to mirror, you can do it with the *Mesh > Symmetrize* tool. If the axis is not good you can change it in the *Operator* box:

[image]

If you have a lot of symmetrize operations to do, it's better to give it a *Mirror* modifier.

Comment: imma try it on my blender Thank for the Help

Comment: HOLY SHIT thanks for the Tip sire now the edge on the left and right is symetrical a video also help me Thanks alot tbh the video the one that make me undestand lel

Answer (score 3):

Create a single loop cut across the middle of your object then, with the loop still selected, use CTRL-B to bevel it. Moving the mouse during the bevel operation moves the resulting edges symetrically. Make sure you only have a single cut enabled during the bevel by scrolling the mouse wheel down.

[image]

Comment: see, this is what i mean from comment turn to video its much easier to understand and what the ** idk it was that easy with that way.